# Can Army Helmets be modified? If yes, how?

Tags: fallout-4

I spent some time modifying other gear leather/metal/combat armor, I got rank 1 of the armorer perk but the standard army helmet is not even showing up in the item list when I use a armor workbench.

What's going on there? Do I need further ranks or different perks? I didn't think so because other modifications are shown in the menu even if I can't craft them yet and other perks seem to be specific for other things like modifying melee weapons or guns.

Is it just that this item cannot be modified at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [GamePedia's Fallout 4 wiki for the Army Helmet](http://fallout.gamepedia.com/Army_helmet) - the Army Helmet has no modification slots and cannot be modified.

Comment: well that's unfortunate, thanks for the clarification though.

Comment: @garglblarg There are other helmets which can be modified, including the metal helmet.

Comment: The Mining Helmet can be modified for light color, but that's it.

Doing the Railroad quests eventually unlocks a ballistic mesh upgrade that can be applied to a variety of previously un-modable clothing and headwear items. I'm not sure if the Army Helmet is specifically among them.

Comment: The Army Helmet is not among them, @T.J.L. There's a list in this answer: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/252762/108003 It's 
    Battered Fedora (+1 Luck)
    Green Rag Hat (10 Energy Resist)
    Trilby Hat (+1 Cha)
    Newsboy Cap (+1 Cha)